# Don't revoke and reaward tag badges when the tag is renamed

Tags: feature-request, bug, tag-badges

When we [renamed the tag `mathmode` to `math-mode` on tex.sx](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2096/4012), all `mathmode` tag badges were revoked and new `math-mode` badges were awarded. This led to all information on the initial awarding of the badges being lost. Worse even, the new badges were awarded with gold first, so that our [top user got his gold `math-mode` badge before the bronze one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg?tab=badges&sort=recent).

Since there will be more such tag-renamings to be done on tex.sx, it'd be nice if this pitfall could be ruled out first, so that tag badges are simply renamed along with their tag.

Comment: Yeah. People like to keep the chronology of things.